# 'this was nullptr' when adding unique_ptr to unordered_map

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointers, unique-ptr

I am creating a simple demo project but I am getting stuck at adding a `unique_ptr` to an unordered list, somehow it adds the key but not the pointer and later on when I try to call a method on the pointer I get the 'this was nullptr error'.

I have a base class `Scene` that is responsible for storing the pointers and adding them to the map like this:

```
void Scene::addGameObject(const std::string& name, const GameObjectParams& params)
{
    m_objects.try_emplace(name, std::make_unique<GameObject>(params));
}

bool Scene::containsGameObject(const std::string& name)
{
    if (m_objects[name] != NULL)
        return true;

    return false;
}

GameObject& Scene::getGameObject(const std::string& name)
{
    auto it = m_objects.find(name);

    if (it != m_objects.end())
        return *it->second;


}

void Scene::drawScene()
{
    for (const auto& object : m_objects)
        object.second->draw(); // <--------here the error gets thrown
}
```

If I call this method from a class that has a `scene` as member it works fine, per example:

```
//GameLayer.h
class GameLayer 
{
private:
    // GameScene is derived class from Scene
    GameScene m_gameScene;
};

//GameLayer.cpp
m_gameScene.addGameObject(
   "player",
   {
       Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
       Vector3f(100.0f, 70.0f, 1.0f),
       Quaternion(),
       Vector4f(1.0f),
       fighter
    }
);
```

But now when I try to add a new object from the derived class itself it adds the key but no pointer

```
void GameScene::spawnLaser(Vector3f pos)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        std::string name = std::to_string(i);
        if (!this->containsGameObject(name))
        {
            m_lasers.emplace_back(name);
            this->addGameObject(
                "laser",
                GameObjectParams {
                    Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                    Vector3f(100.0f, 70.0f, 1.0f),
                    Quaternion(),
                    Vector4f(1.0f),
                    nullptr
                }
            );
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The `GameObject` is the object that should be created with `std::make_unique`

```
GameObject::GameObject(const GameObjectParams& params)
    : m_position(params.position.x, params.position.y, params.position.z),
    m_scale(params.scale.x, params.scale.y, params.scale.z),
    m_rotation(),
    m_texture(params.texture),
    m_color(params.color)
{
}

void GameObject::setTexture(cheetah::Texture* texture)
{
    m_texture = texture;
}

void GameObject::setPosition(const cheetah::Vector3f& position)
{
    m_position.x = position.x;
    m_position.y = position.y;
    m_position.z = position.z;
}

void GameObject::translate(const cheetah::Vector3f& position)
{
    m_position.x += position.x;
    m_position.y += position.y;
    m_position.z += position.z;
}


void GameObject::draw()
{
    // 'this was nullptr' gets thrown here
    if (m_texture != nullptr)
    {
        Renderer2D::drawQuad(DrawTexturedQuadParams{ m_position, m_scale, m_rotation, Vector4f(1.0f), m_texture });
    }
    else
    {
        Renderer2D::drawQuad(DrawQuadParams{ m_position, m_scale, m_rotation, m_color });
    }
}
```

It seems as if `make_unique` doesn't create a new object but I have no idea why.

Comment: I appreciate that you've tried to only give us the relevant code (as opposed to dumping your whole project on us). But it looks like you may have given us too little. Can you reduce your complicated project down to a simple example that can still reproduce your issue (a [MCVE])? As of now, there's no way for us to run your code and debug your issue.

Comment: Not enough here to answer. There should be no difference, and `make_unique` can't really fail without throwing an exception, in which case `try_emplace` would never be called. (I somewhat suspect `containsGameObject`, though.)

Comment: How do you implement `containsGameObject(name)` (is it const)? `return m_gameScene[name] != nullptr;` would be wrong for example.

Comment: @Jarod42 No it is not const(it should though) I have added the implementation of containsGameObject and some extra code for clarification

Comment: @scohe001 I've added extra code, if more is needed let me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code:

```cpp
bool Scene::containsGameObject(const std::string& name)
{
    if (m_objects[name] != NULL)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

If `name` does not exist in the map, the map's `operator[]` will add `name` with a **default-constructed `std::unique_ptr`** that holds a `nullptr`.  You need to use `m_objects.find(name)` instead of `m_objects[name]`:

```cpp
bool Scene::containsGameObject(const std::string& name) const
{
    return (m_objects.find(name) != m_objects.end());
}
```

In this code:

```cpp
GameObject& Scene::getGameObject(const std::string& name)
{
    auto it = m_objects.find(name);

    if (it != m_objects.end())
        return *it->second;


}
```

If `name` is not found in the map, the return value is *indeterminate*.  You need to either:

- return a pointer instead of a reference so that you can return `nullptr` if `name` is not found (and then update the caller to check for `nullptr`):

```cpp
GameObject* Scene::getGameObject(const std::string& name)
{
    auto it = m_objects.find(name);

    if (it != m_objects.end())
        return it->second.get();

    return nullptr;
}
```

- continue to return a reference, but throw an exception if `name` is not found:

```cpp
GameObject& Scene::getGameObject(const std::string& name)
{
    // std::unordered_map::at() throws std::out_of_range if the key is not found...
    return *(m_objects.at(name)->second);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't test it right know but I will test and accept this first thing in the morning.